# C# Multiply Each row of array by set of factors

Tags: c#, arrays, multiplication

I have a multidimensional array and I want to multiply each row of it by a single dimensional array containing factors to create a new multidimensional array. However, the number of rows in the multidimensional array will vary from one run to the next, so I'll need a way to loop the multiplication through each row of the multidimensional array until the last row is reached.

Here is a simple example, I have multidimensional array:
{ { 1, 2, 3, 4}, { 5, 6, 7, 8}, { 9, 10, 11, 12} }

and I want to multiply each row by:
{0.5, 0.4, 0, 0.8}

to get:
{ { 1*0.5, 2*0.4, 3*0, 4*0.8}, { 5*0.5, 6*0.4, 7*0, 8*0.8}, { 9*0.5, 10*0.4, 11*0, 12*0.8} }

I've tried to use .Length within a for loop using the example code.

```
double [] factors = {0.5, 0.4, 0, 0.8};

int [,] myarray = new int [3,4] {
{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
{ 5, 6, 7, 8},
{ 9, 10, 11, 12}
};

double [] output = new double[myarray.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < myarray.Length; ++i)
    output[i] = myarray[i] * factors;
```

I'm getting syntax errors that extension method 'Length' cannot be applied to type int, and also indexing with [] cannot be applied to type int.

Comment: You need to create a second (inner) loop, going over the elements of `factors`. C# can't do vector multiplication by itself.

Comment: You might want to consider using a jagged array `int[][]` instead of a 2D array `int[,]`.  When using a 2D array you need to use `GetLength(int dimention)` to get the size of a given dimension.

Comment: Also your code produces an error about using the wrong number of indices for `myarray`, and not an error about `Length` being applied to an `int`.  Make sure to post the error that matches the code.

Comment: If you change the code to `output[i] = myarray[i/4, i%4] * factors[i%4];` you'll get the results, but in a single array of length 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a ragged array. Multidimensional arrays exist, but are poorly supported and almost nobody uses them. If you use a jagged array, you can be more concise. More importantly, you can be more ***intentional*** about it:

```
double[][] myArray = getMeSomeData();
double[]   factors = getMeSomeRowFactors();

foreach (var row in myArray)
{
  MultiplyRow(row, factors)
}

. . .

void MultiplyRow( double[] row, double[] factors )
{
  for ( int col = 0 ; col < row.length ; ++col )
  {
    row[col] = row[col] * factors[col];
  }
}
```

Or even better: use Linq:

```
double[][] myArray = getMeSomeData();
double[]   factors = getMeSomeRowFactors();

myArray = myArray
          .Select( row => row.Select( (cell, i) => cell * factors[i] ).ToArray() )
          .ToArray()
          ;
```

Or even [arguably] better;

```
double[][] myArray = getMeSomeData();
double[]   factors = getMeSomeRowFactors();

myArray = myArray
          .Select( Multiply(factors) )
          .ToArray()
          ;

. . .
Func<double,int,double[]> Multiply( double[] factors )
{
  return (cell, i) => cell * factors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you find it useful, but you can achieve it by using **MathNet.Numerics**:

> PM> Install-Package MathNet.Numerics

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using System.Linq;

...

var myarray = new double[3, 4]
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4},
    { 5, 6, 7, 8},
    { 9, 10, 11, 12}
};

var factors = new double[4] { 0.5, 0.4, 0, 0.8 };

var matrix1 = Matrix.Build
    .DenseOfArray(myarray);
var matrix2 = Matrix.Build
    .DenseOfRows(Enumerable.Repeat(factors, matrix1.RowCount));

var res = matrix1.PointwiseMultiply(matrix2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of each dimension by using the method [`GetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength):

```
double[,] output = new double[myarray.GetLength(0), myarray.GetLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myarray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        output[i, j] = myarray[i, j] * factors[j];
    }
}
```

In case your array is huge, you can speed up the calculation by using all processors/cores of your PC:

```
Parallel.For(0, myarray.GetLength(0), i =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myarray.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        output[i, j] = myarray[i, j] * factors[j];
    }
});
```